# Flexslider 1.8 go to item

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a question for The Flexslider jQuery plugin, 1.8 version. How can I go to a slide manually? I searched and found a code, but it does not work properly.

```
$('.flexslider').slider.flexAnimate(2, true);
```

I got the "$(".flexslider").flexAnimate is not a function" error

Answer (score 11):

You can go to the third slide like this:

```
var slider = $('#your-slider').data('flexslider');
slider.flexAnimate(2);
```

And this way too:

```
$('#your-slider').flexslider(2);
```

Comment: Can you give a slide an ID and go directly to that slide by ID, in case the numbering of the slides changes later on?